# Angular ошибка $injector:modulerr при подключении ngCookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Подключаю ngCookies

```
//app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'myApp.script',
]);

//script.js
angular.module('myApp.script', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$http', '$scope', '$cookies', function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {
    $scope.cookieUser = $cookies.get('username');
}]);
```

Получаю ошибку

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я забыл подключить в html файле angular-cookies.js как это скзанно [тут](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)